# Deploy NWJS with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nwjs

I am developing an app with NWJS, now I am thinking in the deploy process, what I need is install the app into different machines that will use that app, the problem that I see is if I change some file I will need install again into each machine, I was reading about docker and if I understood fine, I can make an Image and download the last version of the app into each machine that use the app.

The Question is if can I upload the app into a container and download that into each machine?, and How can I search the documentation for do that?.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Lookup Dockerfile  ...  Then lookup docker-compose.yaml which is where you define particulars for your app

Comment: Are all of the target machines on the same network by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've cheated my way into a solution, this could work for you, depending on what your exact requirements are.

In one scenario, I have a shared network folder that allows machines to launch the NWJS app via the network share, so every time I update the file and someone relaunches their short-cut, they have a fresh copy.

The remote users, who are not directly on our same network, has their copy in a DropBox folder - which - of course - automatically update as I drop the new copy into that folder.

None of these solutions are as "clean" as an installer, but, for our use case, works rather well.  It's a bonus that DropBox handles the downloading of the new copy of the file automatically.